# Storing Item Relationships in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

## Background

I want to be able to store complex relationships between products in a MySQL database.

I currently have two tables. The first is a list of products:

```
ID | sku | division | retired
```

The second table is a relationship table

```
ID | prod1 | relation | prod2
```

With the idea being that `prod2` has `relation` to `prod`.

#### Example Rows

Product Table:

```
1 | lamp | household  | false
2 | lamp-short | household  | false
3 | chair| household | false
4 | desk | household | false
5 | desk-realwood | household | false
6 | desk-extratall | household | false
6 | couch | household | false
```

Relations Table:

```
1 | 1 | child | 2   <- short lamp is child of lamp
2 | 4 | child | 5   <- real wood desk is child of desk
2 | 4 | child | 6   <- extra tall desk is child of desk
```

Then on a single product page for `lamp`, I'd like to have a "Related Products" box, so I need to pull in all related products. So I need an SQL query, that given the table names of `products` and `product_relations` and the `ID` of the current product, can pull in all rows in the `products` table that are related to the current product.

IE, if I'm looking at `lamp`, I need to pull in `lamp-short`.

I think I need to use a JOIN, but when I've tried it, I can't get it to work.

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `product_relations` on products.id = ( product_relations.prod2 WHERE product_relations.prod1 = 1 )
```

`5` being provided to the query.

## Question

How would I write my query if I knew the ID of the current product, to get all related products?

Comment: `WHERE product_relations.prod1 == 1` remove one of the equal signs here. Might not solve it but it needs to be `WHERE product_relations.prod1 = 1` syntatically speaking of course.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, when I change it to `==`, I get an SQL error from phpMyAdmin of #1064.

Comment: your query failed then. Far as I know, there shouldn't be 2 equal signs.

Comment: I misread what you wrote, backwards. You are correct about that.

Comment: It's probably also going to fail because you have your WHERE clause hanging out inside of your `ON` because of those parentheses which is nonsense. Your query is very close if you get rid of those parentheses as it takes the same form as the second one in my answer.

Comment: What about the other way? If your product is 'lamp-short' - do you want 'lamp' to be shown in the list?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, no, because this would be used when a user is already on the Lamp product page. This query would build up a list of related products, so you wouldn't need a link to the page you are already on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to get the related product sku and it's relationship to the original product searching by it's sku, you could use:

```
SELECT rp.sku, r.relation
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN relations r ON p.id = r.prod1
    INNER JOIN product rp on r.prod2 = rp.id
WHERE p.sku = '<original sku>'
```

This can be shortened, if you are searching by the original product's id, since then you don't really need the `p` aliased table above:

```
SELECT rp.sku, r.relation
FROM relations r
    INNER JOIN product rp on r.prod2 = rp.id
WHERE r.prod1 = '<original product id>';
```

And you can add to that WHERE clause to filter by specific `r.relation` types, like 'Child' or what have you.

Comment: Yep, this works! Is the renaming of table names to single letters just a matter of reducing overall characters?

Comment: Yes, that's one reason to use an alias. Another is to change the symantics so your tables/subqueries make sense. If you look at that first query, we reference the `products` table twice. The first time I name it `p` for "product" and the second `rp` for "related product". I usually go with smaller names too, because it's easier and I'm lazy. The last reason, is because, like in that first query, I use `products` table twice, so they both have to have a distinct alias so they can be referred to explicitly in other portions of the sql.

Comment: I've written up several variations of that ... find child from parent, find parent from child, find any related, etc. I'd like to put them in here for reference, either appended onto my question or onto your answer. Do you have a preference?

Comment: No preference. Feel free to add to the answer with examples, or you can add your own answer for future searchers.

Answer (score 1):

If they are children:

```
SELECT *
FROM products a
JOIN product_relations b
ON a.id = b.prod1
WHERE a.id = product_id_to_find
```

If you want all related:

```
SELECT *
FROM products a
JOIN product_relations b
ON a.id = b.prod1 OR a.id = b.prod2
WHERE a.id = product_id_to_find
```

Comment: That does look right. But wouldn't the last line of your first query be `b.prod2`, not `a.id`?

Comment: No. The where clause is the place where you restrict the results to the product ID you want to find relations for. You would replace product_id_to_find with the ID of the product you want the relations.

Answer (score 0):

These are entirely based on JNevill's answer. I'm adding them here and a more detailed reference for myself and others now that I understand how it works.

```
/***********************************************************************/
/******** GET ALL PRODUCTS "related" TO PRODUCT 1 (AND REVERSE) ********/
/***********************************************************************/

SELECT *
FROM products
JOIN product_relations
ON products.id = product_relations.prod2
WHERE product_relations.prod1 = 1 OR product_relations.prod2 = 1 AND product_relations.relation = "related"



/***********************************************************************/
/**************** GET THE CHILD PRODUCTS OF PRODUCT 1 ******************/
/***********************************************************************/

SELECT *
FROM products
JOIN product_relations
ON products.id = product_relations.prod2
WHERE product_relations.prod1 = 1 AND product_relations.relation = "child"



/***********************************************************************/
/**************** GET THE PARENT PRODUCT OF PRODUCT 1 ******************/
/***********************************************************************/

SELECT *
FROM products
JOIN product_relations
ON products.id = product_relations.prod1
WHERE product_relations.prod2 = 1 AND product_relations.relation = "child"
```

By flipping the lookup mechanics on the above, we don't have to have a `child` and a `parent` row in the `product_relations` table. The `child` row works for both.

```
/***********************************************************************/
/******** GET THE SUCCESSOR (NEW VERSION) PRODUCT OF PRODUCT 1 *********/
/***********************************************************************/

SELECT *
FROM products
JOIN product_relations
ON products.id = product_relations.prod2
WHERE product_relations.prod1 = 1 AND product_relations.relation = "successor"

/***********************************************************************/
/******* GET THE PREDECESSOR (OLD VERSION) PRODUCT OF PRODUCT 1 ********/
/***********************************************************************/

SELECT *
FROM products
JOIN product_relations
ON products.id = product_relations.prod2
WHERE product_relations.prod1 = 1 AND product_relations.relation = "predecessor"
```